# Pymongo Aggregation with multi-fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate using Pymongo with multiple fields, but I haven't found a way to get the correct value.

I need to get count of total files by 2 fields: `time` and `state`

`time` is a datetime object through pymongo, and I was able to get only yy/mm/dd using

```
'$group': { "_id":{
            "date":{"$concat": [
                   {"$substr": [{"$year": "$date"}, 0, 4 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$month": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
              ]}},
             "count":{"$sum": 1}}
```

This can get extract the correct date for me and count the number of logs, but now I need to also group by `state` so it becomes `GROUP BY date, state` in mysql

I tried adding it inside `_id`

```
'$group': { "_id":{
            "date":{"$concat": [
                   {"$substr": [{"$year": "$date"}, 0, 4 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$month": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
              ]}},
             "_id":{"state":"$timeline.state"},
             "count":{"$sum": 1}}
```

and it creates multiple outputs in the format like `{u'count': 4111, u'_id': {u'state': [0, 1]}}`, the 0 and 1 are codes for different states. The date is nowhere to be found.

I then tried

```
'$group': { "_id":{
            "date":{"$concat": [
                   {"$substr": [{"$year": "$date"}, 0, 4 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$month": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
                   "-",
                   {"$substr": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
              ]}},
             "state":"$timeline.state"},
             "count":{"$sum": 1}}
```

and I got `failed: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

This looks like I didn't get the brackets at the right place, but no matter how I change the format, the same error remains. Now I'm wondering if it's really the bracket's problem. Most importantly, how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a compound `_id` field in your `$group` stage like this:

```
"$group": { 
    "_id":{
        "date":{
            "$concat": [
                { "$substr": [ { "$year": "$date" }, 0, 4 ] }, 
                "-", 
                { "$substr": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] },
                "-",
                { "$substr": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] }
            ] 
        }, 
        "state": "$timeline.state" 
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
}
```

Comment: I see. So everything has to be inside `_id` bracket. I think I got it to work now. Having just one `count` would work, right? I don't need to somehow count the `date` one first then count `state` another time?